# CORS blocked in wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I use WSO2is 5.7.0 with my angular 6 app, i tried make api call from my app but i have a cors error: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at`

I already activated the cors enabled in oauth and authenticationendpoint, i edited de `WEB-INF/web.xml` of both webapps with this lines:

```xml
<filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

        <init-param>
                <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
                <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In authenticationendpoint i copy the cors libraries from oauth to authenticationendpoint webapps in lib folder and edited the pom.xml file with this lines:

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany.wso2</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0.wso2v1</version>
</dependency>
```

After this, restart the service, i and have the same problem `Cross-Origin Request Blocked`

in my angular app service i make the request as follow:

```
const httpHeaders = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders()
                .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
                .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        };

this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:9443/commonauth`, payload, httpHeaders)
```

i think is neccesary enable cors support from tomcat but i don't know how do that, What other alternatives do I have besides enabling cors?

My sources:

`https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Invoking+an+Endpoint+from+a+Different+Domain`
`https://hasanthipurnima.blogspot.com/2016/05/applying-cors-filter-to-wso2-identity.html`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The endpoint you are trying to invoke is registered as a servlet inside the Identity Server and you need to configure the web.xml file in `repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/` to apply the headers to your endpoint.

You can add the `org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter` to the above-mentioned file to allow the required domains. More info can be found from [tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter). Sample config would look like below.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>https://www.somedomain.com</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/commonauth</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```