# How to allow CORS access in WSO2IS 5.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to access my identity server from a different domain, I am using REST endpoints provided by the WSO2IS for login, signup, user info, etc.

I have tried the following configuration without any success:

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Invoking+an+Endpoint+from+a+Different+Domain
2. http://hasanthipurnima.blogspot.com/2016/05/applying-cors-filter-to-wso2-identity.html
3. [CORS blocked in wso2 identity server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58301123/cors-blocked-in-wso2-identity-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below config to `<IS-HOME>/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/tomcat/web.xml.j2` in WSO2 Identity Server distribution pack.

Note that below is a sample taken from https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps#run-in-dev-mode. This should work for you as well.

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
            <param-value>https://localhost:9000, https://localhost:9001</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
                   <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
                   <param-value>Location</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

In the above for `param-value` of `<param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>` Add the hosts you want to allow CORS(You can add multiple Comma-separated or Whitespace-separated values). If the host has a port, that should be included as well. Ideally it should be in the format `<protocol>://<host>:<port>`.

Also in the above for `param-value` of `<param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>`. Add the HTTP methods you will need (You will always need the OPTIONS method as that is the one used for the CORS check).

You can configure the URLs to allow CORS using the `<url-pattern>` config. `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` means CORS is allowed for all URLs of the Identity Server.

For more info on the CORS filter configurations refer: http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-configuration.html

Comment: Thank you, your response led me to the solution, the issue was resolved by editing __identity.xml.j2__ as suggested on the GitHub [link](https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps#run-in-dev-mode) you provided.